# Inserting MULTIPLE Checkboxes into a Database column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to insert the value of multiple checkboxes if they are checked into one column in my database.

Here is what I have...

```
if(!empty($_POST['dyuhdb'])) {
    foreach($_POST['dyuhdb'] as $dyuhdb) {
        $dyuhdb . ",";
    }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MRF (Q1) VALUES ('". $dyuhdb ."')";

<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dyuhdb[]" value="1">1</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dyuhdb[]" value="2">2</label>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="dyuhdb[]" value="3">3</label>
</div>
```

For some reason, if 1 and 2 are ticked, only 2 will enter into my Database?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why the name is `dyuhdb[]` ??

Comment: It's the first letter of each question in the form, it's a very long form with multiple groups of checkboxes, I have only provided one example as I can duplicate the changes on each.

Comment: Not a good practise to store checkbox values in a single column.

Comment: Putting `$_POST` data directly in your query is a [super bad idea](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the following line,

```
$dyuhdb . ",";
```

In each iteration of `foreach` loop you're overwriting the variable `$dyuhdb`. Instead simply use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to join the array element with a string(`,`) and use it in your `INSERT` query, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['dyuhdb']) && count($_POST['dyuhdb'])){
    $checkbox_values = implode(",", $_POST['dyuhdb']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO MRF (Q1) VALUES ('". $checkbox_values ."')";

    // execute your query
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection. Also see [how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @D.Ashbridge Just one more thing, there's no need to quote your checkbox values, `implode(",", $_POST['dyuhdb'])` will do just fine. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There will be an extra `,` in your Query. You could avoid the same by using built in [**`implode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function instead of looping post data.

```
if(!empty($_POST['dyuhdb'])) {
   /* foreach($_POST['dyuhdb'] as $dyuhdb) {
        $dyuhdb . ",";
    }*/

    $dyuhdb = implode(",",$_POST['dyuhdb']);
}
```